# Type or property (NSUInteger (aka unsigned int)) does not match type of ivar (int)

Tags: objective-c, nsuinteger

I want to declare a `NSInteger` variable in my ViewController, but I get an error.

In my ViewController.h I have

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController{
    NSInteger currentSection;
    //Other stuff  
  }

  @property (assign,nonatomic) NSUInteger currentSection;
@end
```

and in my ViewController.m I have:

```
@implementation MainViewController

//Other stuff
@synthesize currentSection;
```

But I get this error:

> Type of property 'currentSection' ('NSUinteger' (aka 'unsigned int')) does not match type of ivar 'currentSection' ('int')

Why do I get this error with one simple instruction?
I'm using Xcode 4.4 with ARC.

Comment: Read the error message again. Or maybe for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking the compiler to synthesize a `NSUInteger` property with a `NSInteger` ivar. You have to decide what the type of the property should be and adapt the type of the ivar accordingly.

Note that unsigned integer are not equivalent to (implicitly signed) integer. Casting one to the other might give you unexpected results.